# Not Recently Used algorithm using map

Tags: go, hashmap

I have a need where I need to implement NRU (Not Recently Free) algorithm.
Current data structure is just simple map, something like

```
map[string]bool
```

Basically this is hashmap for string to availability. But
instead of just being `bool`, I want to include some timestamp so that along
with whether a particular `string` is avail or not, I also will pick Not Recently Freed (Oldest) string. Wondering about how to modify the Go's 
Data structure.

I am thinking of

```
map[string]bool+timestamp
```

That way, if let's say highest bit is set, that shows available or not
and timestamp will help me to search through based on time.

Comment: If you are looking for LRU style caches you may want to consider http://github.com/jwells131313/goethe

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store two types in the value part of a map you can do so by creating a new struct type:

```
type Value struct {
  avail bool
  timestamp time.Time
}
```

Then you can create a map as follows:

```
m := map[string] Value{}
```

And add to the map:

```
m["some-value"] = Value{avail:true, timestamp: time.Now()}
```

Comment: This is what exactly I ended up using. I think this works, but quite inefficient IMO.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unusual to want to keep empty slots in a map.  If you want to remove an element from a map, you can [delete](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Deletion_of_map_elements) it, and then you can use the [two-result form index expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) to test whether something is in the map or not.

```
m := make(map[string]int)
m["x"] = 1
if _, ok := m["x"]; ok {
        fmt.Printf("x is there")
}
delete(m, "x")
if _, ok := m["x"]; !ok {
        fmt.Printf("x is not there")
}
```

Usually you need more than just a map of key to value to implement least-recently-used; you need some other side data structure like a [doubly-linked list](https://godoc.org/container/list) to remember which order they've been used in.  (If you do have some persistent value like a timestamp, a heap would work too.)  You could store pairs of actual values and timestamps in the map values, but then you have to search through the whole list to find the oldest one.

```
import "container/list"

type CacheValue struct {
        Key string
        Value int
}

type Cache struct {
        values map[string]*list.Element
        lru *list.List
}

func makeCache() *Cache {
        return &Cache{
                values: make(map[string]*list.Element),
                lru: list.New(),
        }
}

func (c *Cache) Put(k string, v int) {
        cv := CacheValue{Key: k, Value: v}
        el := c.lru.PushFront(&cv)
        c.values[k] = el
}

func (c *Cache) Get(k string) int {
        el, ok := c.values[k]
        if ok {
                c.lru.MoveToFront(el)
                return el.Value.(*CacheValue).Value
        }
        return 0
}

func (c *Cache) DeleteOldest() {
        el := c.lru.Back()
        if el != nil {
                delete(c.values, el.Value.(*CacheValue).Key)
                c.lru.Remove(el)
        }
}
```